# How to print out specific length of spacing between numbers?

Tags: java

I want to be organize with the output so I want to do something like this

```
   1   2   3   4   5
........
  91  92  93  94  95
........
 101 102 103 104 105
etc....
```

So I was trying to figure out how to line them up with the correct amount of spacing between each number.

my first attempt is doing everything manually like this

```
System.out.print("  " + counter);
```

using a loop

Comment: show us your attempt first

Comment: btw check for the java's `printf()` method

Answer (score 1):

Read [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) in the docs.

You can use `System.out.format` using `%<width>d` where you replace `<width>` with the width you require (make sure everything fits in!):

```
System.out.format("%4d", number); // align to width of 4
```

To add newlines use `%n`:

```
System.out.format("%4d%n", 1);
System.out.format("%4d%n", 12);
System.out.format("%4d%n", 123);
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a percent sign missing somewhere?

Comment: That should be `%4d`

Comment: nice, been programming java for half a year, i didn't know how to adjust the width in java. I know how in c++. %4d is correct, I just tested thanks!